# Pdf Created from Html using UIViewPrintFormatter not showing local images

Tags: html, ios, pdf, uiwebview, pdf-generation

I am creating pdf from an html file with images.I tried creating from from Html as well as from UIWebView by loading the html in to web view .The following are the methods use for both approach

1.From html

```
   func exportHTMLContentToPDF(HTMLContent: String) {
    let printPageRenderer = CustomPrintPageRenderer()

    let printFormatter = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: HTMLContent)
    printPageRenderer.addPrintFormatter(printFormatter, startingAtPageAtIndex: 0)

    let pdfData = drawPDFUsingPrintPageRenderer(printPageRenderer)

    pdfData.writeToFile(pdfPath(), atomically: true)

}
```

2.From UiWebView by loading Html

```
func createPdfFromViewFormatter(viewFormatter:UIViewPrintFormatter) {

    let printPageRenderer = CustomPrintPageRenderer()

    printPageRenderer.addPrintFormatter(viewFormatter, startingAtPageAtIndex: 0)
    let pdfData = drawPDFUsingPrintPageRenderer(printPageRenderer)

    pdfData.writeToFile(pdfPath(), atomically: true)


}
```

Pdf creation method`

```
    private func drawPDFUsingPrintPageRenderer(printPageRenderer: UIPrintPageRenderer) -> NSData! {
    let data = NSMutableData()

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(data, CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: printPageRenderer.printableRect.width, height: printPageRenderer.printableRect.height), nil)


    printPageRenderer.prepareForDrawingPages(NSRange(location: 0, length:printPageRenderer.numberOfPages() ))


    for i in 0..<printPageRenderer.numberOfPages() {


        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()

        printPageRenderer.drawPageAtIndex(i, inRect: UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds())

    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()


    return data
}
```

The issue is the image in the html is is not shown in the created pdf.But it is displayed while loading it in a UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem : 
[IOS Swift sharing PDF documents with images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40022032/ios-swift-sharing-pdf-documents-with-images)
I believe it's a bug. The only solution I found so far is to create a dummy UIWebView that I hide. I load the HTML in the UIWebView and then create the PDF. Here is my code :

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    hiddenWebView.loadHTMLString(htmlText, baseURL: nil)
    hiddenWebView.isHidden = true
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    pdfDocument = getPdf()
    let tmpDirectoryURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
    let fileURL = tmpDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent("document.pdf")
    pdfDocument.write(to: fileURL, atomically: false)
    documentWebView.loadRequest(URLRequest(url: fileURL))
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue and finally I got the solution. Hope anyone help this solution. Just Replace createPdfFromViewFormatter methods 's code.
`
func createPdfFromViewFormatter(viewFormatter:UIViewPrintFormatter) {

```
 // 2. Assign print formatter to UIPrintPageRenderer
    let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()
    render.addPrintFormatter(formatter, startingAtPageAt: 0)
    
    // 3. Assign paperRect and printableRect
    let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 595.2, height: 841.8) // A4, 72 dpi
    let printable = page.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)
    
    render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: page), forKey: "paperRect")
    render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: printable), forKey: "printableRect")
    
    // 4. Create PDF context and draw
    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRect.zero, nil)
    
    for i in 1...render.numberOfPages {
        
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        let bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()
        render.drawPage(at: i - 1, in: bounds)
    }
    
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
    
    // 5. Save PDF file
    let path = "\(NSTemporaryDirectory())\(filename).pdf"
    pdfData.write(toFile: path, atomically: true)
```

}
`

Call createPdfFromViewFormatter method Like That

let pdfData = createPdfFromViewFormatter(viewFormatter: webView!.viewPrintFormatter())